# A redis command ERR:wrong number of arguments hiredis

Tags: c++, c, redis, lua

**when I am executing the "script load" command through hiredis adapter I am getting the error wrong no of argument. The same command through Redis client is running fine.**

```
reply_r= (redisReply *)redisCommand(con_r,"script","load", "return 1");
      string stemp="";
      if(reply_r->len>0)
        {
          string stt(reply_r->str);
          stemp=stt;
          //printf("Commad Reply : %s\n", reply_r->str);
    
        }
      freeReplyObject(reply_r);//  should free the object after reading the data
      return stemp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reply_r= (redisReply *)redisCommand(con_r,"scrips load %s", "return 1");
      string stemp="";
      if(reply_r->len>0 && reply_r!=NULL)
        {
          
          stemp=string(reply_r->str);          
    
        }
      freeReplyObject(reply_r);//  should free the object after reading the data
      return stemp;
```

Comment: Better check if the returned `reply_r` is nullptr. Off-topic: you can also try [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus), which has built-in support for `SCRIPTS LOAD` command: `auto sha = redis.script_load("return 1");`